# PWA get media backend url

Tags: media-images, magento2.3.5, pwa, react

Is there a readily available way to get Media url path from component ?

I know there is a `getMediaUrl` fetching from graphql in `venia-concept/webpack.config.js`

Tried in my component: `global.MAGENTO_MEDIA_BACKEND_URL` but that's undefined.